Laravel version 11 Authentication
I'm trying to make authentication for both the User and Admin from the same login view and within the same controller
the authentication is successfully done until the store method redirects the user to the route then the route checks the middleware and returns "False" or redirects the user back to the login page
Note in Laravel version 11 there is no kernel.php instead, it uses bootstrap/app.php
//app.php
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->web(append: [
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    ]);
    $middleware->api(prepend: [
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ]);
    $middleware->alias([
        'auth.admin' => AdminMiddleware::class,
        'auth.user' => UserMiddleware::class,
        'auth' => UserMiddleware::class,
    ]);

//Admin Middleware
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    
    dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check());
    return redirect()->route('login');
}

//Store method
public function store(LoginRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    
    $request->authenticate();
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    
    if (Auth::guard('web')->check()) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'));
    }

    if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('index'));
    }
    
    return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['email' => 'Authentication error']);
}

//Route example
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
return view('dashboard');

})->middleware('auth.user')->name('dashboard');
I read a lot about declaring or configuring the middleware in the new version until I added it in the app.php but the user still when trying to access the middleware it's returns false, the user is authenticated when I print the result in the store method it returns true but when it reaches the route then middleware it returns false

Which middleware user is trying to access?During accessing of which route middleware return false? Note you have assigned same middleware for both auth & auth.user

when trying to access route dashboard as an example it return false same as accessing the routes of admins too

The Problem was in the database !!
I created the id in the database in capital letter "ID" which does not match the id in that check method was searching for so it was returning false, after I changed it to small letters it succeeded
